# Some problems with extracting data from three separate tables

Tags: sql

I was presented with the question:

*Write a SQL command to display for each employee who has a total
distance from all journeys of more than 100, the employee’s name,
the total number of litres used by the employee on all journeys. (The
number of litres for a journey is distanceInKm divided by kmPerLitre.)*

For the following set of data:
[image: Dataset]

and I've more or less hit a brick wall. I had a question similar earlier and eventually some user told me to resolve it with an inner join, and I've been doing those since, but this question uniquely asks for data from all three tables. This is my solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.NAME, sum(T.distanceInKM/C.kmPerLitre)
FROM Employe E, TravelCost T, CAR C
GROUP BY T.distanceInKm,E.name,C.kmPerLitre
HAVING SUM(distanceInKM) > 100;
```

(Please ignore the small differences; my Employee table is named Employe and my distanceSinceService column is just called "distance")

But this gives me absolutely insane outputs and I have no real clue what's happening. We did some group by's in class but none of them were as difficult as this so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Your sql statement does not really join the tables on any column(s)

Comment: I dont know if you can join 3 tables together. I can get it to return the ID's of the employees that have travelled more than 100km by slightly modifying my table but I'm not sure how to correctly then also get the average for litres per km

Comment: Please do always state the RDBMS (vendor and version) and **please** do not paste your sample data as a picture. This makes it very hard to set up a scenario...

Comment: Sorry for that. Anyways, I think I have solved my own question, not sure if the data I got is right. I am sure that I got the correct employees back but I dont have the time to check if its right. I will therefore cautiously answer my own question.

Comment: In general when it comes to GROUP BY: The selected columns that are not argument to set functions are the ones that should be listed in the group by clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version that joins your tables and should give you what you expect

```
SELECT E.NAME
     , SUM(T.distanceInKM/C.kmPerLitre) AS NumLitres
     , SUM(T.distanceInKM) AS TotalDistanceInKm
  FROM Employe E
 INNER
  JOIN TravelCost T
    ON E.id = T.employeeId
 INNER 
  JOIN CAR C
    ON T.carRegNo = C.regNo
 GROUP 
    BY E.name
HAVING SUM(T.distanceInKM) > 100
;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that mine ommitted Smith, probably due to the unnecessary GROUP BY. I'll select this as the correct answer and delete my own.

Comment: You were faster than me :-) +1 from my side

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct, because you don't want to sum on c.KmPerLitre.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE(id INT,name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Employee VALUES
 (1,'Smith')
,(2,'Patel')
,(6,'Bennett')
,(7,'Booch');

DECLARE @Car TABLE(regNo VARCHAR(100),distanceSinceService INT,kmPerLitre FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @Car VALUES
 ('FF06DDS',122,10)
,('EE07SSA',110,8)
,('FG07BAK',165,7)
,('HH08BBW',0,12);

DECLARE @TravelCost TABLE(jouneyID INT,carRegNo VARCHAR(100),employeeID INT,occured DATE,distanceInKm FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @TravelCost VALUES
 (4,'FF06DDS',1,{d'2007-07-11'},90)
,(6,'FG07BAK',2,{d'2007-07-21'},110)
,(11,'EE07SSA',6,{d'2007-07-21'},110)
,(12,'FF06DDS',1,{d'2007-09-05'},32)
,(21,'FG07BAK',7,{d'2007-09-05'},55);

SELECT e.name AS Employee
      ,SUM(tc.distanceInKm) AS SumKm
      ,SUM(tc.distanceInKm/c.kmPerLitre) AS UsedGasoline 
FROM @TravelCost AS tc
INNER JOIN @Car AS c ON tc.carRegNo=c.regNo
INNER JOIN @Employee AS e ON tc.employeeID=e.id
GROUP BY e.name
HAVING SUM(tc.distanceInKm)>100;
```

The result

```
Employee    SumKm   UsedGasoline
Bennett     110     13,75
Patel       110     15,71
Smith       122     12,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm actually not sure that it passes the syntax-check, but if it does - yay! :D

```
SELECT e.Name,
sum(t.DistanceInKm) DistanceInKm,
sum(t.DistanceInKm) / c.KmPerLitre FuelSpent
FROM TravelCost t JOIN Employee e ON t.EmployeeId = e.Id
JOIN Car c ON t.CarRegNo = c.RegNo
GROUP BY e.Name, c.KmPerLitre
HAVING sum(t.DistanceInKm) > 100;
```